# Laravel Telescope connection to mysql problem by using docker network bridge

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, laravel-9, laravel-telescope

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: insert into `telescope_entries` (`batch_id`, `content`, `created_at`, `family_hash`, `type`, `uuid`) values (975528a6-10a8-4f4e-b795-834edf9d71da, {"command":"make:job","exit_code":0,"arguments":{"command":"make:job","name":"Health/ProxmoxHeartBeatJob"},"options":{"force":false,"sync":false,"test":false,"pest":false,"help":false,"quiet":false,"verbose":false,"version":false,"ansi":null,"no-interaction":false,"env":null},"hostname":"debian"}, 2022-09-23 10:01:39, ?, command, 975528a6-0f89-4ef1-89ed-a1ad477ca7e7)) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: insert into `telescope_entries` (`batch_id`, `content`, `created_at`, `family_hash`, `type`, `uuid`) values (975528a6-10a8-4f4e-b795-834edf9d71da, {"command":"make:job","exit_code":0,"arguments":{"command":"make:job","name":"Health\/ProxmoxHeartBeatJob"},"options":{"force":false,"sync":false,"test":false,"pest":false,"help":false,"quiet":false,"verbose":false,"version":false,"ansi":null,"no-interaction":false,"env":null},"hostname":"debian"}, 2022-09-23 10:01:39, ?, command, 975528a6-0f89-4ef1-89ed-a1ad477ca7e7)) at /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759)
[stacktrace]
#0 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(898): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#1 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(878): Illuminate\Database\Connection->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#2 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(722): Illuminate\Database\Connection->handleQueryException()
#3 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(545): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run()
#4 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(497): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement()
#5 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3204): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert()
#6 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php(148): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insert()
#7 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php(262): Laravel\Telescope\Storage\DatabaseEntriesRepository->Laravel\Telescope\Storage\{closure}()
#8 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php(149): Illuminate\Support\Collection->each()
#9 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(663): Laravel\Telescope\Storage\DatabaseEntriesRepository->store()
#10 [internal function]: Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::Laravel\Telescope\{closure}()
#11 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(284): call_user_func()
#12 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(674): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::withoutRecording()
#13 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/ListensForStorageOpportunities.php(65): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::store()
#14 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::Laravel\Telescope\{closure}()
#15 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#16 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(81): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#17 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#18 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()
#19 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1177): Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
#20 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->terminate()
#21 /opt/laravel/src/artisan(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->terminate()
#22 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution at /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
[stacktrace]
#0 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct()
#1 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(100): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createPdoConnection()
#2 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(50): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#3 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection()
#4 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(184): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect()
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
#6 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(1169): call_user_func()
#7 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(538): Illuminate\Database\Connection->getPdo()
#8 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(752): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}()
#9 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(898): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#10 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(878): Illuminate\Database\Connection->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#11 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(722): Illuminate\Database\Connection->handleQueryException()
#12 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(545): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run()
#13 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(497): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement()
#14 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3204): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert()
#15 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php(148): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insert()
#16 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php(262): Laravel\Telescope\Storage\DatabaseEntriesRepository->Laravel\Telescope\Storage\{closure}()
#17 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php(149): Illuminate\Support\Collection->each()
#18 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(663): Laravel\Telescope\Storage\DatabaseEntriesRepository->store()
#19 [internal function]: Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::Laravel\Telescope\{closure}()
#20 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(284): call_user_func()
#21 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(674): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::withoutRecording()
#22 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/ListensForStorageOpportunities.php(65): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::store()
#23 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::Laravel\Telescope\{closure}()
#24 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#25 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(81): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#26 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#27 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()
#28 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1177): Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
#29 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->terminate()
#30 /opt/laravel/src/artisan(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->terminate()
#31 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 0): PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution at /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
[stacktrace]
#0 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct()
#1 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(100): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createPdoConnection()
#2 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(50): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#3 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection()
#4 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(184): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect()
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
#6 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(1169): call_user_func()
#7 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(538): Illuminate\Database\Connection->getPdo()
#8 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(752): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}()
#9 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(898): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#10 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(878): Illuminate\Database\Connection->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#11 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(722): Illuminate\Database\Connection->handleQueryException()
#12 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(545): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run()
#13 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(497): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement()
#14 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3204): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert()
#15 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php(148): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insert()
#16 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php(262): Laravel\Telescope\Storage\DatabaseEntriesRepository->Laravel\Telescope\Storage\{closure}()
#17 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php(149): Illuminate\Support\Collection->each()
#18 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(663): Laravel\Telescope\Storage\DatabaseEntriesRepository->store()
#19 [internal function]: Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::Laravel\Telescope\{closure}()
#20 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(284): call_user_func()
#21 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php(674): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::withoutRecording()
#22 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/ListensForStorageOpportunities.php(65): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::store()
#23 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Laravel\Telescope\Telescope::Laravel\Telescope\{closure}()
#24 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#25 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(81): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#26 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#27 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()
#28 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1177): Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
#29 /opt/laravel/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->terminate()
#30 /opt/laravel/src/artisan(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->terminate()
#31 {main}
"}